# Create object that inherit the interface

Tags: c#, oop, abstract-class

I have two model interface `ILoanModel` and `IAmortizationModel`.

```cs
public interface ILoanModel
{
    string ID { get; set; }
    IEmployeeModel Borrower { get; set; }
    // ******* other propeties *********
    ICollection<Model.IAmortizationModel> AmortizationTable { get; set; }
}

public interface IAmortizationModel
{
    string ID { get; set; }
    ILoanModel Loan { get; set; }
    // ******* other propeties *********
}
```

I create another interface that will handle the computation and other function

```cs
public interface IAmortization
{
    // Compute and generate amortization table
    Model.ILoanModel Generate(Model.ILoanModel loan);
    // **** Other function *****
}
```

Currently I have 3 type of loans and all them have same way of computation and generation of amortization table.

```cs
public abstract class Amortization : Controller.Computation.Interface.IAmortization
{
    public virtual Model.ILoanModel Generate(Model.ILoanModel loan)
    {
        // **** other code *******
        //Create the amortization table
        decimal last_Amortization_RunningBalance = loan.Amount;
        loan.AmortizationTable = new List<Model.IAmortizationModel>();

        for (int x = 1; loan.NumberOfPayment >= x; x++)
        {
            // having problem here because Model.IAmortizationModel is a interface
            var newAmortizationRow = new Model.IAmortizationModel
            {
                ID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
                AmortizationAmount = loan.AmortizationPaymentAmount,
                AmortizationInterest = loan.AmortizationPaymentAmount* loan.Nominal,
                AmortizationPrepayment = 
                    loan.AmortizationPaymentAmount 
                    - (loan.AmortizationPaymentAmount * loan.Nominal),
                AmortizationOutstandingBalance = 
                    last_Amortization_RunningBalance 
                    - (loan.AmortizationPaymentAmount 
                        - (loan.AmortizationPaymentAmount * loan.Nominal)),
                Sequence = x
            };

            last_Amortization_RunningBalance -= 
                newAmortizationRow.AmortizationOutstandingBalance;
            loan.AmortizationTable.Add(newAmortizationRow);
        }
    }
}
```

My problem now is generating new `IAmortizationModel` that will be added to the `loan.AmortizationTable`. How can I get the type of `loan.AmortizationTable` and create?

Comment: Why are you using interfaces? Do you have multiple implementations of the loan model and amortization model? If you do, and you really need to instantiate an object you could make the method generic and add a `new()` constraint to it.

Comment: @IanMercer yes, sample the car loan and emergency loan. car loan have field where need to specify the car brand and model while the emergency loan need what emergency occurred.

Comment: IMHO add a `protected abstract IAmortizationModel Factory(...)` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to make it generic and add a generic constraint with `new()`:

```
public virtual Model.ILoanModel Generate<T>(Model.ILoanModel loan)
   where T:IAmortizationModel, new()
```

and then call `new T()`

An alternative option would be to pass a generator function:

```
public virtual Model.ILoanModel Generate(Model.ILoanModel loan,
  Func<IAmortizationModel> generator)
```

and call `generator()`